# How can I add or remove shadows from a td / th with "position: sticky" on scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I made a table with the header and the last column fixed using `position: sticky`. I want to remove the shadows from the last column when the scroll bar is horizontally at the end, and remove the shadows from the header when the scroll bar is vertically at the beginning. [In AntDesign there is an example](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-fixed-columns-header) of the desired result, but in this case the table has shadows only in the fixed columns, not in the header.

Although I don't want solutions with Scroll Event Listener because of performance reasons (see [Scroll-linked effects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Scroll-linked_effects)), if someone solves it that way, they can share it for reference and help other people.

The code is also available at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-with-fixed-column-and-headers-h37kf).

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  height: 5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.fixed {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
}

.fixed-top {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed-right {
  border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-left: 1rem;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed-top.fixed-right {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), -5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="fixed fixed-top">Animal</th>
      <th class="fixed fixed-top">Age</th>
      <th class="fixed fixed-top">Country</th>
      <th class="fixed fixed-top">Sentence</th>
      <th class="fixed fixed-top">Color</th>
      <th class="fixed fixed-top fixed-right">Programming Language</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Sable</td>
      <td>15 yo</td>
      <td>Japan</td>
      <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
      <td>Purple</td>
      <td class="fixed fixed-right">Kotlin</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Toco toucan</td>
      <td>35 yo</td>
      <td>Brazil</td>
      <td>
        Sed tortor erat, imperdiet a enim quis, placerat rhoncus nisl.
      </td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td class="fixed fixed-right">Swift</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bull</td>
      <td>42 yo</td>
      <td>Spain</td>
      <td>Donec vitae risus urna.</td>
      <td>Red</td>
      <td class="fixed fixed-right">JavaScript</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brown bear</td>
      <td>17 yo</td>
      <td>Russia</td>
      <td>Proin gravida et velit ut congue.</td>
      <td>Green</td>
      <td class="fixed fixed-right">Python</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need to have a CSS class that will remove shadow from the `td` and `th` elements.

```
.noShadow {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Now, there are 2 ways you can do this via javscript:

1. Intersection Observer API
2. Scroll event

#### How to do this via Intersection Observer API?

You need to observe two `td` elements via two instances of `InterSectionObserver`: one instance to observe one `td` element each. When the observed `td` elements come into view, we want to add `noShadow` CSS class to the table row or column. Similarly, `noShadow` class will be removed when observed `td` elements move out of the view.

I have added `observed-column` class on one of the `td` elements that will be observed for adding or removing shadow from last column and added `observed-row` class on one of the `td` elements to add or remove shadow from the header.

Here's the javascript code you need

```
const lastColumn = document.querySelectorAll(".fixed-right");
const header = document.querySelectorAll(".fixed-top");
const tableContainer = document.querySelector("main");
let rowHasShadow = false;
let columnHasShadow = true;

const options = {
  root: tableContainer,
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 1
};

const rowObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    // '.observed-row' element is in view, remove shadow from header
    rowHasShadow = false;
    header.forEach(th => {
      if (th.classList.contains('fixed-header') && !columnHasShadow) {
        th.classList.add("noShadow")
      } else if (!th.classList.contains('fixed-header')) {
        th.classList.add("noShadow")
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    // '.observed-row' element is not in view, add shadow to header
    rowHasShadow = true;
    header.forEach(th => th.classList.remove("noShadow"));
  }
}, options);

rowObserver.observe(document.querySelector(".observed-row"));

const columnObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    // '.observed-column' element is in view, remove shadow from last column
    columnHasShadow = false;
    lastColumn.forEach(th => {
      if (th.classList.contains('fixed-header') && !rowHasShadow) {
        th.classList.add("noShadow");
      } else if (!th.classList.contains('fixed-header')) {
        th.classList.add("noShadow");
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    // '.observed-column' element is not in view, add shadow to last column
    columnHasShadow = true;
    lastColumn.forEach(th => th.classList.remove("noShadow"));
  }
}, options);

columnObserver.observe(document.querySelector(".observed-column"));
```

#### Demo

```js
const lastColumn = document.querySelectorAll(".fixed-right");
const header = document.querySelectorAll(".fixed-top");
const tableContainer = document.querySelector("main");
let rowHasShadow = false;
let columnHasShadow = true;

const options = {
  root: tableContainer,
  rootMargin: "0px",
  threshold: 1
};

const rowObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    // '.observed-row' element is in view, remove shadow from header
    rowHasShadow = false;
    header.forEach(th => {
      if (th.classList.contains('fixed-header') && !columnHasShadow) {
        th.classList.add("noShadow")
      } else if (!th.classList.contains('fixed-header')) {
        th.classList.add("noShadow")
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    // '.observed-row' element is not in view, add shadow to header
    rowHasShadow = true;
    header.forEach(th => th.classList.remove("noShadow"));
  }
}, options);

rowObserver.observe(document.querySelector(".observed-row"));

const columnObserver = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
  if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    // '.observed-column' element is in view, remove shadow from last column
    columnHasShadow = false;
    lastColumn.forEach(th => {
      if (th.classList.contains('fixed-header') && !rowHasShadow) {
        th.classList.add("noShadow");
      } else if (!th.classList.contains('fixed-header')) {
        th.classList.add("noShadow");
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    // '.observed-column' element is not in view, add shadow to last column
    columnHasShadow = true;
    lastColumn.forEach(th => th.classList.remove("noShadow"));
  }
}, options);

columnObserver.observe(document.querySelector(".observed-column"));
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  height: 5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.fixed {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
}

.fixed-top {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.fixed-right {
  border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-left: 1rem;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed-top.fixed-right {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
    -5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.noShadow {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top">Animal</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top">Age</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top">Country</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top">Sentence</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top observed-column">Color</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top fixed-right fixed-header">Programming Language</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Sable</td>
        <td>15 yo</td>
        <td>Japan</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td class="fixed fixed-right observed-row">Kotlin</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Toco toucan</td>
        <td>35 yo</td>
        <td>Brazil</td>
        <td>
          Sed tortor erat, imperdiet a enim quis, placerat rhoncus nisl.
        </td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td class="fixed fixed-right">Swift</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bull</td>
        <td>42 yo</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>Donec vitae risus urna.</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td class="fixed fixed-right">JavaScript</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brown bear</td>
        <td>17 yo</td>
        <td>Russia</td>
        <td>Proin gravida et velit ut congue.</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td class="fixed fixed-right">Python</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```

You can also view this demo on codesandbox

[image: Edit Table with fixed column and headers]

#### How to do this via Scroll event?

Add a scroll event listener on `main` element. Inside the event handler, you need to check 2 things:

1. if `scrollLeft` is equal to `scrollWidth - clientWidth`, add the `.noShadow` class on all the `td` elements in last column
2. if `scrollTop` is equal to zero, add `.noShadow` class on all `th` elements

Following is the javascript code you need along with the `noShadow` css class

```
const lastColumn = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-right');
const header = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-top');
const tableContainer = document.querySelector('main');

tableContainer.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  removeShadowFromColumn();
  removeShadowFromHeader();
});

function removeShadowFromHeader() {
  if (tableContainer.scrollTop === 0) {
    header.forEach(th => th.classList.add('noShadow'));
  } else {
    header.forEach(th => th.classList.remove('noShadow'));
  }
}

function removeShadowFromColumn() {
  const widthDiff = tableContainer.scrollWidth - tableContainer.clientWidth;

  if (tableContainer.scrollLeft === widthDiff) {
    lastColumn.forEach(th => th.classList.add('noShadow'));
  } else {
    lastColumn.forEach(td => td.classList.remove('noShadow'));
  }
}

removeShadowFromHeader();
```

#### Demo

```js
const lastColumn = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-right');
const header = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-top');
const tableContainer = document.querySelector('main');

tableContainer.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
  removeShadowFromColumn();
  removeShadowFromHeader();
});

function removeShadowFromHeader() {
  if (tableContainer.scrollTop === 0) {
    header.forEach(th => th.classList.add('noShadow'));
  } else {
    header.forEach(th => th.classList.remove('noShadow'));
  }
}

function removeShadowFromColumn() {
  const widthDiff = tableContainer.scrollWidth - tableContainer.clientWidth;

  if (tableContainer.scrollLeft === widthDiff) {
    lastColumn.forEach(th => th.classList.add('noShadow'));
  } else {
    lastColumn.forEach(td => td.classList.remove('noShadow'));
  }
}

removeShadowFromHeader();
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 20rem;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
}

th,
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  height: 5rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 2rem;
}

.fixed {
  background-color: white;
  position: sticky;
}

.fixed-top {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed-right {
  border-left: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
  box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-left: 1rem;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.fixed-top.fixed-right {
  box-shadow: 4px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), -5px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 2;
}

.noShadow {
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top">Animal</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top">Age</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top">Country</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top">Sentence</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top">Color</th>
        <th class="fixed fixed-top fixed-right">Programming Language</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Sable</td>
        <td>15 yo</td>
        <td>Japan</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</td>
        <td>Purple</td>
        <td class="fixed fixed-right">Kotlin</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Toco toucan</td>
        <td>35 yo</td>
        <td>Brazil</td>
        <td>
          Sed tortor erat, imperdiet a enim quis, placerat rhoncus nisl.
        </td>
        <td>Orange</td>
        <td class="fixed fixed-right">Swift</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bull</td>
        <td>42 yo</td>
        <td>Spain</td>
        <td>Donec vitae risus urna.</td>
        <td>Red</td>
        <td class="fixed fixed-right">JavaScript</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brown bear</td>
        <td>17 yo</td>
        <td>Russia</td>
        <td>Proin gravida et velit ut congue.</td>
        <td>Green</td>
        <td class="fixed fixed-right">Python</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```

You can also view the demo on codesandbox

[image: Edit Table with fixed column and headers]

**P.S.** For performance reasons, i suggest you do this via first approach that uses [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).